# Converting every n rows of the table to single row with n columns by Kusto Query Language

Tags: kql

I have the following output for my query:

```
LogEntry
'@timestamp': '2022-12-11T12:36:59.258Z',
msName: 'frontend',
level: 'ERROR',
message: 'Get categories failed with the error: Error: Request failed with status code 503'
userId: ''
req: 'http://ssm.att.com/'
'@timestamp': '2022-12-11T12:38:507.258Z',
msName: 'frontend',
level: 'INFO',
message: 'clearSession failed with the error: SyntaxError: Exponent part is missing a number in JSON at position 2'
userId: ''
req: 'http://ssm.att.com/'
```

and so on i.e., this pattern repeats every 6 rows.

I would like to perform some manipulation by Kusto Query Language to get one row with 6 columns for every 6 rows i.e.

```
timestamp                  msName    level  message          userId  req
2022-12-11T12:36:59.258Z   frontend  ERROR  Get categor...           http://ssm.att.com
2022-12-11T12:38:507.258Z  fromtend  INFO   clearSession ...         http://ssm.att.com
```

etc.

Please advise

I just tried to see which function can be used but did not find something useful

---

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |

https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

LogEntry
'@timestamp': '2022-12-11T12:36:59.258Z',
msName: 'frontend',
level: 'ERROR',
message: 'Get categories failed with the error: Error: Request failed with status code 503'
userId: ''
req: 'http://ssm.att.com/'
'@timestamp': '2022-12-11T12:38:507.258Z',
msName: 'frontend',
level: 'INFO',
message: 'clearSession failed with the error: SyntaxError: Exponent part is missing a number in JSON at position 2'
userId: ''
req: 'http://ssm.att.com/'

There is no additional column

Comment: Hi Dmitry **(1)** Please provide all sample data as datatable /CSV /TSV (just put it As Is without trying to beautify it). **(2)** Is there an additional column that connects all 6 rows together? **(3)** How does the original data looks like?

Comment: Not here :-) please put it in your post and remove the comment

Comment: See my previous comment

Comment: I do not understand how to post it, should I ask a new question?

Comment: Can I ask you via MS teams?

Comment: Ping me in 5 minutes

Comment: Sorry, had to leave the office yesterday, can you explain me how to attach files here?

Comment: Let me know if we can chat via MS teams

Comment: Don't attach files, just edit your answer. I'll edit your answer and add an example.

Comment: I don't get the data format. Is it a single string with newlines?